# Fusion Table API bug, not able to handle WHERE clauses with equality on numeric fields?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm getting strange results from the FusionTable API. Specifically, it seems unable to handle a simple select statement with equality constraints on numeric values.  Any query I try of the following form:

[SELECT COUNT() FROM 1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI WHERE AGE=41](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT+COUNT%28%29+FROM+1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI+WHERE+AGE%3D41&key=AIzaSyBT_ZCriV-Tm78KsJiQp6KKhjDwMhP0tYM)

yields zero records:

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "count()"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [ "0" ]
 ]
}
```

By contrast, a range constraint works fine:

[SELECT COUNT() FROM 1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI WHERE AGE>40.99 AND AGE<41.01](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT+COUNT%28%29+FROM+1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI+WHERE+AGE+%3E40.99+AND+AGE%3C41.01&key=AIzaSyBT_ZCriV-Tm78KsJiQp6KKhjDwMhP0tYM)

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "count()"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [  "362" ]
 ]
}
```

Maybe the numbers underneath aren't integers?  [SELECT AGE FROM 1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI WHERE AGE>40.99 AND AGE<41.01](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT+AGE+FROM+1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI+WHERE+AGE%3E40.99+AND+AGE%3C41.01&key=AIzaSyBT_ZCriV-Tm78KsJiQp6KKhjDwMhP0tYM) returns

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "AGE"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [ "41" ],
  [ "41" ],
  [ "41" ],
  ...359 more...
]}
```

Now, maybe there's some floating point representation error going on?  I thought that small integers can be represented exactly as floats (even if some decimal fractions, e.g. 0.1, are repeating decimals in binary).

It seems unlikely that a bug in Fusion Table SQL would get by without being discovered by others, so perhaps it's there's something unique to how [this particular FusionTable](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI) is loaded?

**UPDATE:**

While the query appears to fail using the new Fusion Table API above, it succeeds using the old Fusion Table SQL API (recently deprecated):
[www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20COUNT()%20FROM%204579147%20WHERE%20AGE%20LIKE%2041](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20COUNT%28%29%20FROM%204579147%20WHERE%20AGE%20LIKE%2041)

which returns this JSON response:

```
count()
362
```

Also, the new FusionTable API appears confused by numeric values:

- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE = 41`  yields `0` (incorrect)
- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE = "41"`  yields `0` (incorrect)
- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE MATCHES 41`  yields `362`
- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE LIKE 41`  yields `362`
- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE LIKE "41"`  yields `362`
- `SELECT COUNT() FROM 4579147 WHERE AGE LIKE "%41%"`  yields `362`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recently introduced bug that will be fixed shortly. As described it does only affect numeric equality queries with aggregation. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: No worries, thanks for the confirmation.  Might this be related to another issue with aggregation and values?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533395/partially-incorrect-results-from-google-fusion-table-via-ajax-but-correct-via-c

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with AGE = 41 in that table:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S580613IY6U

Something about the count() is causing the query to fail

Comment: Brilliant to think of cross checking using the FT user interface.  Looking just now, that UI doesn't seem to show the type of each column (e.g. Integer, Float, String, etc.) Following your lead I crosschecked against the deprecated Fusion Table SQL API, which also works fine.